# What is the purpose of session.key in C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\Icorn

Tags: iis, diskmanagement

The size of the C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\Icorn\session.key file (and a similar one, session.key.bk) has gone beyond 8 GB. I want to free up space on this server.

What can I do to safely reclaim that space? Is it an IIS setting? Is it ok to just delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a standard IIS file. You should check your website code and configuration to determine what is utilizing this file. Most likely it is a plugin of some sort.

Comment: Spot on, Hyppy. It's a custom plugin developed internally. Thanks!